# O que tem de errado com minha a função da minha classe para diminuir o valor?

Tags: c++, classes

Estou desenvolvendo uma classe para poder administrar melhor meus itens de forma mais organizada. Quando o valor da variável for menor que o valor minimo era para ir pro valor máximo, porém, na pratica isso não está ocorrendo, vai parar uns valores estranhos:

Ao pressionar a tecla <kbd>F2</kbd> 7 vezes eu tenho isso no *console* do meu algoritmo:

```
Item texto: Testando um float
Valor maximo do item: 0.5
Valor atual: 0.4

Item texto: Testando um float
Valor maximo do item: 0.5
Valor atual: 0.3

Item texto: Testando um float
Valor maximo do item: 0.5
Valor atual: 0.2

Item texto: Testando um float
Valor maximo do item: 0.5
Valor atual: 0.1

Item texto: Testando um float
Valor maximo do item: 0.5
Valor atual: 1.49012e-08

Item texto: Testando um float
Valor maximo do item: 0.5
Valor atual: -0.1

Item texto: Testando um float
Valor maximo do item: 0.5
Valor atual: 0.5
```

A partir do valor `0.1` já era pra ter ido para o valor `0.5` em vez de ir para o valor `1.49012e-08`

Minha classe:

```
class cVarFloat
{
private:
       float            fValue;
       float            fValueSet;
       float            fMax;
       float            fMin;
       char             ItemText[100];
public:
       float            GetMax()
       {
           return this->fMax;
       }

       float            GetValue()
       {
           return this->fValue;
       }

       char*            GetItemText(void)
       {
           return this->ItemText;
       }

       void         SetValue(float fValue)
       {
           this->fValue = fValue;
       }

       /*
           É nessa função que eu estou tendo o problema
       */
       void         DecValue(void)
       {
           if (this->fValue <= this->fMin)
               this->fValue = this->fMax;
           else
               this->fValue -= this->fValueSet;
       }

       void         IncValue(void)
       {
           if (this->fValue >= this->fMax)
               this->fValue = fMin;
           else
               this->fValue += fValueSet;
       }

       cVarFloat(const char* ItemText, float fMin, float fMax, float fValueSet, float fInitValue)
       {
           this->fMin = fMin;
           this->fMax = fMax;
           this->fValueSet = fValueSet;
           this->fValue = fInitValue;
           strcpy(this->ItemText, ItemText);
       }
   };
```

No meu main:

```
int main()
{
    // Primeiro argumento = Texto da classe
    // Segundo argumento = Valor mínimo
    // Terceiro argumento = Valor máximo
    // Quarto argumento = Valor na qual vai aumentar/diminuir o valor da variável
    // Quinto argumento = Valor inicial da variável

    cVarFloat Teste("Testando um float", 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.1f, 0.5f);

    while (1)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F1) & 1)
        {
            Teste.IncValue();
            cout << "Item texto: " << Teste.GetItemText() << "\nValor maximo do item: " << Teste.GetMax() << "\nValor atual: " << Teste.GetValue() << endl << endl;
        }

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F2) & 1)
        {
            Teste.DecValue();   // problema nessa função
            cout << "Item texto: " << Teste.GetItemText() << "\nValor maximo do item: " << Teste.GetMax() << "\nValor atual: " << Teste.GetValue() << endl << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problema

O problema tem a ver com comparação de igualdade em valores de virgula flutuante. Isto torna-se um problema pois a representação para vários dos valores não é exata o que acaba dando resultados inesperados!

Considere o seguinte exemplo:

```
double a = 0.1 + 0.2;
double b = 0.3; 

cout<<(a == b)<<endl; //0 -> falso
```

Que apresenta `0` na consola, indicando assim que `0.1+0.2` difere de `0.3`!

[Veja por si mesmo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/puugIB)

Na verdade `0.1` não é possível de representar de uma forma exata num `double`, devido à forma como é codificado no sistema binário.

Fazendo uma comparação entre sistemas:

- 1/10 não é codificável de forma exata e finita em binário
- 10/3 não é codificável de forma exata e finita em base decimal.

Isto faz com que `0.1` em binário seja então uma dizima infinita periódica escrita como:

```
0.00011001100110011001100110011001100110011....
```

Normalmente notada como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então quando escrevemos:

```
double c = 0.1;
```

O valor que `c` tem realmente é

```
0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

Ou mesmo em `float`:

```
float d = 0.1f; //0.100000001490116119384765625
```

Que era precisamente o `1.49012e-08` que lhe aparecia na consola. Estes valores acabam sendo mostrados na consola como `0.1` apesar de não o serem, e que impossibilitam comparações de forma exata.

Este é apenas um entre vários exemplos de valores que não são representáveis de forma exata em binário.

### Solução

No seu caso simples poderia utilizar uma comparação com margem de erro para substituir a igualdade, normalmente chamada de epsilon:

```
float epsilon = 0.0001f;

if (fabs(a-b) < epsilon){
```

Aqui comparamos se a diferença dos dois é baixa o suficiente para que os consideremos iguais. Note que foi utilizada função `fabs` da biblioteca `<cmath>` para obter o valor absoluto de um `float`.

Como pretende comparar com menor ou igual pode até criar uma função que faça isso automaticamente:

```
bool igualMenor(float a, float b, float epsilon){
    if (fabs(a-b) < epsilon) return true;

    return a-b < 0;
}
```

Agora tem apenas que aplicar nos seus `ifs`:

```
void DecValue(void)
{
    //chamando a função que compara passando um epsilon razoável para o caso em questão
    if (igualMenor(this->fValue, this->fMin, 0.0001f))
        this->fValue = this->fMax;
    else
        this->fValue -= this->fValueSet;
}
```

Isto não irá impedir o `cout` de mostrar o valor `0.1` na sua representação exata, algo que podemos forçar utilizando `cout<<fixed` garantindo assim que o valor é o que se esperava visualmente.

[Veja o seu código com esta solução aplicada no Ideone](https://ideone.com/D3Eemm)

<sup>Alterei ligeiramente a introdução de dados para que o resultado fosse apresentável no Ideone</sup>

### Melhorias

Esta solução embora funcione também poderá trazer alguns problemas no que diz respeito ao epsilon, uma vez que este não é escalado ao `a` e `b`. Nesse caso pode optar por dividir o resultado da subtração por um dos valores, o que reduz a escala dos mesmo face ao epsilon:

```
fabs((a-b)/b) < epsilon
```

No entanto isto trará problemas em divisões com `0`. Por isso teria que ampliar a lógica para algo bem mais complexo como (que seria exagerado para o seu exemplo):

```
bool quaseIgual(float a, float b, float epsilon) {
    float absA = fabs(a);
    float absB = fabs(b);
    float diff = fabs(a - b);

    if (a == b) { // atalho para resolver infinitos
        return true;
    } else if (a == 0 || b == 0 || diff < FLT_MIN) {
        // a ou b são zeros e extremamente perto entre si
        // erro relativo é ignorável neste caso
        return diff < (epsilon * FLT_MIN );
    } else { // usar erro relativo
        return diff / min((absA + absB), FLT_MAX ) < epsilon;
    }
}
```

Incluindo o `<float.h>` para aceder às constantes `FLT_MIN` e `FLT_MAX`

Referencias:

- [Guia de aritmética de virgula flutuante (em inglês infelizmente)](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que a aritmética de pontos flutuantes (float) não tem precisão infinita. Se você somar valores floats e tentar comparar por igualdade nem sempre você vai ter o resultado esperado. 1.49012e-08 é um valor bem próximo de 0, mas ainda é > 0.

O melhor a fazer nessa situação é: evitar usar floats para iterações, ou usar uma função de comparação que tenha uma certa margem de erro. Você pode fazer o for usando int por exemplo é calcular o valor "atual" dividindo por 10.

Comment: Poderia me dar um pequeno exemplo de como é feito? Para mim não ficou claro de como seria feito essa função.

Answer (score 0):

Comparações com números de ponto flutuante são o inferno! Evite-as!

Nesse caso, você pode evitar todas essas comparações pré calculando em uma *array* os valores dentro do intervalo desejado.

As operações de incremento e decremento agora trabalham movendo a posição do indice e lendo os valores contidos na *array*, usando aritmética de números inteiros:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>


class cVarFloat
{
    private:

        int         nPos;
        float       *pfArray;
        int         nArrayLen;
        float       fValueSet;
        float       fMax;
        float       fMin;
        float       fInitValue;
        std::string ItemText;

    private:

        void Initialize( void )
        {
            unsigned int i = 0;
            nArrayLen = static_cast<int>( std::ceil( (fMax - fMin) / fValueSet) ) + 1;
            pfArray = new float[ nArrayLen ];
            for( float f = fMin; f <= fMax; f += fValueSet, i++ ){
                pfArray[i] = f;
                if( this->fInitValue == f )
                    this->nPos = i;
            }
        }

    public:

        cVarFloat( std::string ItemText, float fMin, float fMax, float fValueSet, float fInitValue ) :
            nPos(0), fValueSet(fValueSet), fMax(fMax), fMin(fMin), fInitValue(fInitValue), ItemText(ItemText) { this->Initialize(); }

        virtual ~cVarFloat() { delete [] pfArray; }

        float GetMax(void) { return this->fMax; }
        std::string GetItemText(void) { return this->ItemText; }
        float GetValue(void) { return this->pfArray[ this->nPos ]; }

        void DecValue(void) { if( this->nPos == 0 )  this->nPos = this->nArrayLen - 1; else this->nPos--; }
        void IncValue(void) { if( this->nPos == this->nArrayLen - 1 ) this->nPos = 0; else this->nPos++; }
};


int main(void)
{
    cVarFloat Teste( "Testando um float", 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.1f, 0.5f );

    for( int i = 0; i < 15; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << Teste.GetValue() << std::endl;
        Teste.DecValue();
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < 15; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << Teste.GetValue() << std::endl;
        Teste.IncValue();
    }

}
```

Saída:

```
0.5
0.4
0.3
0.2
0.1
0
0.5
0.4
0.3
0.2
0.1
0
0.5
0.4
0.3
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Os formatos de ponto flutuante tem limites de precisão e não garantem a representação exacta de certos números. No caso do formato de precisão simples (float) o valor relativo deste limite de precisão ronda os 1e-7 e no formato de dupla precisão (double) ronda os 1e-15.  O teu código realizou umas quantas operações algébricas sobre números expressos no formato de precisão simples.  Como as operações acumularam uns erros de arredondamento, no final obtiveste valores inferiores ao limite de precisão.  Está tudo a funcionar como era esperado.

Para lidares com este tipo de situações precisas de ter dois aspectos em consideração: o primeiro é saber qual a ordem de grandeza do resultado esperado.  Se estás a lidar com números que são múltiplos de 0.5 e esperas que um resultado possível seja 0.0 então um resultado de 1e-8 é claramente zero.  Para resolver este problema basta arredondar os resultados tendo em conta a ordem de grandeza dos valroes esperados.  O segundo aspecto é a propagação de erros de arredondamento.  Cada operação algébrica em variáveis de ponto flutuante tem um potencial de introdução de erros de arredondamento.  Com cada operação que realizas, esses erros de arredondamento vão-se acumulando.  Há operações, como a divisão, que tem o potencial para fazer explodir o valor do erro.  Se precisares mesmo de exactidão nos resultados então precisas de analisar as operações algébricas para evitar propagações desnecessárias dos erros de arredondamento e prever qual o limite máximo dos erros.